# Programatically setting environment variable via Visual Studio Package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am developing a [VSPackage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166424.aspx) in C# for Visual Studio 2010 and above. The package enables the user to enable/disable the functionality of the package via Menus in the IDE (among other things it does).

**Goal**:
When the package functionality is enabled, I want to raise some environment variable, but it is to be set only when the application is run in "Debug mode" (Debug > Start Debugging [F5]), something like:
VS_COOL_PKG_ENABLE=1

and I want this env variable to be visible to the debugee (the application being debugged).

**Solutions that didn't work**:

1.**Environment change**: Invoking
[Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it didn't work because the package live in the address space of the IDE (devenv.exe), and the VS debugger (msvsmon.exe) is a different process (child process of devenv.exe) that is created only once the IDE is started, therefore any following changes I make in the parent process (IDE) will not be reflected in the VS debugger, and therefore the application (child process of the debugger) will not see them as well.

Why is that?
Because when I run my project in "Debug mode", the process tree of the Debugee is like this:
IDE (devenv.exe) > VS Debugger (msvsmon.exe) > Application

and the phase in which I make the changes is (right before the app is started):
IDE (devenv.exe) > VS Debugger (msvsmon.exe)

so "VS Debugger" is oblivious of the environment changes.

2.**Project properties**:
I have found a workaround, by programatically modifying the "Environment" setting of all of the projects in the solution
(i.e. Project Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Environment)
using the VCDebugSettings.Environment property.

But the cons of this solution are:

- The environment variable is also set when the user "Starts with Debugging" (Ctrl+F5)
- It messes with user settings, this is not a clean solution

**Bottom line**
I want to dynamically raise this environment variable but to raise it only when the user "Starts with Debugging".

Maybe there's some API/event in the EnvDTE (Visual Studio Automation Model) that enables me to "inject" environment variable right before it starts debugging, or invoke functions in the context of the VS debugger process (msvsmon.exe), and by that I can set the environment variable, and then when the application is spawned (by the debugger) it will see the changes.

I am willing to accept answers that involve hacks, such as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38205/change-environment-of-a-running-process).